# I don't have the option to fold code anymore in vscode in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-folding

Recently I discovered that the little arrow next to lines in vscode, that allows you to fold parts of the code, had disappeared. I then noticed this was the case only in my Python files.
I scoped the internet looking for an answer, but nothing worked
I'v tried fixing the setting (by checking that the "folding" setting in the settings UI was ticked) but it did nothing, I tried removing the last extensions I had installed to see if they were interfering or something, but no.

Thanks for the info on #region, but even that doesn't allow me to fold the code. I've tried with the command "fold" from the command palette and with 'Ctrl+Shift+[' and 'Ctrl+Shift+]' but it didn't work

I'm on Arch Linux using VsCode-OSS btw

Comment: try delete config of vs-code before download new one. it's exist in `%app%` I think Can't remember as I don't use windows anymore

Comment: @Abdullah How can you tell they're using Windows?

Comment: What settings did you check exactly? Please [edit] to add the details. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: I just guess. and this is most common.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 8):

Sort of expanding on the other answer, I've worked around it by changing settings for my python-specific workspace and changing the "Folding Strategy" to "indentation" instead of "auto", which seems to be a perfect workaround (for me at least) since Python requires proper indentation anyway and this doesn't mess with global settings

[image of the settings in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvUu3.png)

I'm experiencing the exact same issue in VSCode on Windows (which is how I found this question) - only Python code folding seems to be broken, C++ etc seems to be fine, never noticed it happening before so I think a recent update broke it

Comment: good catch. "Indentation" folding strategy did the trick. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Just adding to what has been said above - with some visuals:

Select (bottom left):   Manage > Settings > filter on **folding**

Then make sure `Editor: Folding` is checked and that `Editor: Folding Strategy` is set to `indentation` - as below

[image]

Finally - close your session of VS Code

When you open VS Code again the folding settings should work.

Remember to **mouseover** to the **left** of `class` or `def` in your code to **fold** - as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Search **folding** in settings, and then check the first one.

You can also use the following code to test whether it is valid

```
# region

# endregion
```

For example:

```
# region hi
print("HelloWorld")
# endregion
```

Comment: For me `Edictor: Folding` was already checked.  However, unchecking it, closing settings, opening settings, and checking it back on triggered code folding to work!

Answer (score 1):

If none of other answers helps you, you can create your custom folding range using `Ctrl+K Ctrl+,` on windows (I hope smth like that is in linux also, try searching `folding range`). Selected lines willbe folded. To delete folding region, use `Ctrl+K  Ctrl+.`.

Answer (score 0):

As said by user3731622 in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74117813/i-dont-have-the-option-to-fold-code-anymore-in-vscode-in-python#comment134387202_74119104), unchecking `Edictor: Folding`, restarting vs-code, and checking it back, may solve the problem.